# Javascript IE vs. Firefox style.visibility implementations

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

I'm sure this is a poor oversight on my part but I'm hoping someone can explain the correct way to use *.style.visibility/*.style.display in a way that works in both IE and Firefox.

Basically, I have a custom tab control. The first tab has a custom MP3 player control in it. When the user clicks on a different tab the music needs to continue to play, even though it is no longer visible.

In IE, this works as advertised but in Firefox when the user clicks on another tab the music stops and the control resets to its initialized state.

```
//<summary>
// Display or hide relevent div areas.
//</summary>
//<param name="divId">The id of the viewable div</param>
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    var elems = new Array("0", "1", "2", "3");
    var hdnView = document.getElementById('<%=hdnCurrentDiv.ClientID %>');

    for (div in elems) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(div);

        if (div == divId) {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
            hdnView.value = divId;
            //highlightSelection(elem);
        }
        else {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get Firefox to behave like IE in that when the user clicks on a tab, the player on the previously selected tab continues to play and just makes that div invisible?

Comment: Having divs with id `"0"` etc is a _really_ bad idea

Comment: This has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: that's why it's a comment and not an answer. It's still a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for bringing nothing to the table.

Comment: you realise that ids in the DOM are made global variables. this means you you have added `window[0]`, `window[1]` etc into global scope. This is a great way to get really annoying bugs.

Comment: Dude, this is a sample stub from a much larger product that has been extracted and re-factored for the explicit purpose of posting on a public forum. I'm here for expert advise regarding a specific problem; not to be told the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of showing/hiding you can set background of each tab to non-transparent color, position them absolutly on top of each other and change their z-index to bring clicked tab to the top of the stack.

This way you don't have a problem with elements beeing destroyed/reset. And you don't have to change the positioning every time a different tab is beeing clicked. All you do is change z-index...

quick example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    ul
    {
        list-style: none;
    }
    li
    {
        display: inline;
    }
    #Tab1, #Tab2
    {
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function toggleTab( tabID )
    {
        for( var i = 1; i<= 2; i++ )
        {
            var id = "Tab" + i;
            if( id != tabID )
            {
                document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex = "1";
            }
        }

        document.getElementById(tabID).style.zIndex = "2";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:toggleTab('Tab1');">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:toggleTab('Tab2');">Link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="position: relative;" id="allTabs">
        <div id="Tab1">
            Tab 1...
        </div>
        <div id="Tab2">
            Tab 2...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `display = 'none'`, firefox destroys the music player. Your alternative options are:

- Just set `visibility = 'hidden';`
- Position the elements absolute and move it to a place far away instead of hiding (-10000, -10000 is a good place to start)

Comment: I think you meant `display: none`, not `display = 'block'`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

display=none will remove the element and all child elements from the document

visibility=hidden the element and children are invisible, but the element exists on the page and takes up space

you could set visibility to hidden and the width and height to 1px or position off the page somewhere, as a semi display none.